# 1054 - Unknown column 'iaiirq.assignedRQQty' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  iaiirq.requisition_id, SUM(iaiirq.quantity) as assignedRQQty, iaipo.requisition_id, 
iaipo.assignedPOQty FROM inv_assign_item_to_inv_requisition as iaiirq
LEFT JOIN (SELECT requisition_id, SUM(purchase_order_quantity) as assignedPOQty from  
inv_assign_item_to_purchase_order GROUP BY requisition_id ) as iaipo on iaiirq.requisition_id = 
iaipo.requisition_id
WHERE  iaiirq.assignedRQQty > iaipo.assignedPOQty 
GROUP BY iaiirq.requisition_id
```

Generating an error like this,

## 1054 - Unknown column 'iaiirq.assignedRQQty' in 'where clause'

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a [on topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and how to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is it not understandable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the error message says iaiirq.assignedRQQty doesn't exist in the table, because u defined it in your select clause instead use HAVING like below.

```
SELECT  iaiirq.requisition_id, SUM(iaiirq.quantity) as assignedRQQty, iaipo.requisition_id, 
iaipo.assignedPOQty FROM inv_assign_item_to_inv_requisition as iaiirq
LEFT JOIN (SELECT requisition_id, SUM(purchase_order_quantity) as assignedPOQty from  
inv_assign_item_to_purchase_order GROUP BY requisition_id ) as iaipo on iaiirq.requisition_id = 
iaipo.requisition_id
GROUP BY iaiirq.requisition_id
HAVING assignedRQQty > iaipo.assignedPOQty
```